# Read value from a pointer to a pointer in a structure (SPI transaction)

Tags: c, spi, esp32

Hi I'm trying read the value of *rx_buffer which is a member of spi_transaction_t struct in the following example.

```
struct spi_transaction_t {
    [...]
    union {
       void *rx_buffer; //< Pointer to receive buffer, or NULL for no MISO phase. Written by 4 bytes-unit if DMA is used.
    uint8_t rx_data[4]; //< If SPI_USE_RXDATA is set, data is received directly to this variable
    };
};  


//Queue transaction
static void send_lines(spi_device_handle_t spi)
{
    esp_err_t ret;
    int x;
    [...]
    for (x=0; x<6; x++) {
        ret=spi_device_queue_trans(spi, &trans[x], portMAX_DELAY);
        assert(ret==ESP_OK);
    }

}

//Dequeue transaction
static void send_line_finish(spi_device_handle_t spi)
{
    spi_transaction_t *rtrans;
    esp_err_t ret;
    for (int x=0; x<6; x++) {
        ret=spi_device_get_trans_result(spi, &rtrans, portMAX_DELAY);
        assert(ret==ESP_OK);
    }
}
```

The code is from this example:
https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/221eced06daff783afde6e378f6f84a82867f758/examples/peripherals/spi_master/main/spi_master_example_main.c#L342

I'm now trying to dequeue the data from *rx_buffer and write it to another buffer. Something like the following, but I'm struggling with the pointer to pointer structure.

```
//Dequeue transaction
static void send_line_finish(spi_device_handle_t spi)
{
    spi_transaction_t *rtrans;
    esp_err_t ret;
    int16_t data_buffer[6];

    for (int x=0; x<6; x++) {
        ret=spi_device_get_trans_result(spi, &rtrans, portMAX_DELAY);
        assert(ret==ESP_OK);
        data_buffer[x] = (int16_t**)rtrans->rx_buffer;
    }
}
```

Edit:
The docs says:

> Normally, data to be transferred to or from a device will be read from
>   or written to a chunk of memory indicated by the rx_buffer and
>   tx_buffer members of the transaction structure. When DMA is enabled
>   for transfers, these buffers are highly recommended [...]

https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/master/docs/en/api-reference/peripherals/spi_master.rst

Comment: Why are you casting a `void*` to an `int16_t**` and then try to assign it to a `int16_t` item? This doesn't make the slightest sense. Any why would you send a memory address over SPI?

Comment: There's supposed to be values where rx_buffer is pointing to and that is what I'm trying to read. And because rtrans is a pointer and rx_buffer is a pointer I thought I could cast that to int16.

Comment: Sending a pointer over SPI is fishy. Why does an external hardware tell your microcontroller where the microcontroller stores its buffers? It still doesn't make sense.  You realize that you are using a `union` and not a `struct`, yes?

Comment: I would say the `union` is part of `struct spi_transaction_t`, isn't it? And that is part of the SPI library from espressif (link above).

Comment: And I don't think that there is a pointer sent over SPI. That's the microcontroller who handles the buffer. IMHO

Comment: It sounds like you want to get the address of the buffer from rx_buffer, then read the data from the buffer. So `int16_t *p = rtrans->rx_buffer; data_buffer[x] = *p;`

Comment: The _only_ reason to use a union with a pointer is if it is getting serialized for transmission over SPI. Which doesn't make any sense, just as serializing a pointer for any other use doesn't make any sense either. And why are structs passed by value for a microcontroller application?

Comment: @stark thanks, exactly what I tried to do but I get a core dump when *p is assigned to data_buffer.

Comment: @Lundin there are other functions in the library which use serialization. But I don't understand enough to clearly see through it

Comment: Please include proper `spi_transaction_t` definition. The comments for `rx_buffer` and `rx_data` explain what is going on.

Comment: Reading that documentation, they apparently use the union members for unrelated purposes, setting rx_buffer to NULL when no read should be done. So they rely on the underlying representation of a null pointer constant somehow, and hoping it isn't the same as the data. This is wildly fishy practice.